# Asus N56VZ won't boot after enabling xhci usb pre boot option in bios

Tags: display, bios, asus-laptop, cmos

To continue from the title, the display doesn't turn on after enabling the usb pre boot option. I have tried taking the laptop apart, removing and replacing the cmos battery with no success. I have checked that all the cables are properly reattached when putting it all back together.

What the hell? Did setting the pre boot option fry a component or the motherboard itself? Any ideas would be deeply appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

to be clear, A. is your laptop powering on but no display? or B. it does not power at all?

> if=A. remove your RAM and clean it with eraser
>
> if=B. check your power source/supply/button/pcb for loose contact

Comment: Yes, it is powering on, but no display is shown. I tried removing the RAM and cleaning it with eraser, but the problem still persists.